# Is there some way to prevent windows from realizing I've disconnected displays

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors

I like arranging my windows in specific layouts but whenever my monitors go to sleep/turn off Windows10 rearranges my windows automatically.

Is there some way to make Windows10 think those monitors are plugged in even when they are powered off?

I understand that this may result in me not being able to get to my other windows easily if my monitor is off, but that's acceptable to me.

Comment: What is the setup as regarding connectors to the monitors?

Comment: I have this problem on multiple setups, but 3 displayport to displayport on one and onboard laptop + usbc to displayport x2 on the other

Comment: how did you arranging  layout? Is it a domain joined computer? As my know, rearrange layout not roll back after reboot or turn off monitor.